# Checking Convergence of an Infinite Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The problem is taken from *Advanced Calculus* by Fitzpatrick, Section 9.1.1f. We are instructed to evaluate the convergence of the given series:

**9.1.1f $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{k + 1}{k^2 + 1}\right)^3$**

My answer below:

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{k + 1}{k^2 + 1}\right)^3 = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{(k + 1)^3}{(k^2 + 1)^3}\right) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k^3}{(k^6 + 6 k^5 + 18 k^4 + 32 k^3 + 36 k^2 + 24 k + 8)} + \frac{(6 k^2)}{(k^6 + 6 k^5 + 18 k^4 + 32 k^3 + 36 k^2 + 24 k + 8)} + \frac{(12 k)}{(k^6 + 6 k^5 + 18 k^4 + 32 k^3 + 36 k^2 + 24 k + 8)} + \frac{8}{(k^6 + 6 k^5 + 18 k^4 + 32 k^3 + 36 k^2 + 24 k + 8}$.

This is an ugly expansion, but we now have rules that will apply; we know, since the powers on $k$ differ between numerator and denominator by no less than 3, that each term in this ugly expansion is less than or equal to $\frac{1}{k^2}$ (also because $k$ starts at 1). By the p-test, $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2}$ converges, so each of the individual terms in the expansion converges, and by the addition property of convergent series, the sum of all four of these convergent series is convergent

Two questions: one, is this actually correct? And two, if it is correct, is there a better way to show this? My attempt seems kind of clunky to me.

Comment: Just use that for $k \ge 2$ we have $\frac{k + 1}{k^2 + 1} \le \frac{1}{k-1}$ and conclude

Comment: The [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) provides a less clunky way of showing this series's convergence.

Comment: @Conrad My bad, deleted my comment, thanks.